# ICorDebug::CreateProcess crash on Windows 8 in .Net 4.5?

Tags: .net, com, windows-8

I have a program in .Net 4.5 using `ICorDebug::CreateProcess` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms232508.aspx). It work on Windows XP, Vista, 7, but not on Windows 8 : my program stop without any message, even in debug mode. But, the same program, in .Net 4.0, work correctly on Windows 8.

Any idea about this?

Thank in advance :)

Comment: What does "my program stops without any message, even in debug mode" mean?  When you step through your program in the debugger, what happens?  What does `CreateProcess` return?  You're going to have to provide a minimal repro--a sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: My program stop running and close, without throw any exception. When I step through my programm, arrived at the execution of this function, the debugger stop, like if I have choose to stop it, without intercept any error in my program. So, CreateProcess is not executed (in any case not correctly), and so return nothing.

Comment: Do you have first chance exception handling enabled?  Have you stepped through the assembly to see what is executing when the process terminates unexpectedly?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. Nothing else than "CreateProcess" is executing at this moment. =/

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are calling the ICorDebug::CreateProcess? I'd like to see the flags that you are using.

Comment: Hello @EtienneBaudoux, I'm from .NET Compatibility Team. Could you post small repro code that demonstrates the problem? In case there are IP issues with posting code on the site, feel free to email at netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com. I will respond back on stackoverflow after looking at the code. --Varun Gupta, Microsoft .NET Framework Compatibility Team.

Comment: Hi,
Ok thank you, I will send you my code by email.

Comment: Thank you @Etieene, I'm looking into your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this will be helpful in diagnosing this problem or not, but I have something similar happening on Windows 8 as well.

We have some legacy VB6 apps that we are trying to test on Win 8.

Several of the apps run other VB6 apps using CreateProcessA.  Some with and some without parameters - usually the command line parm points to a parameter file created in %temp%.

Most of these run just fine.  However, a few of them will not run at all.  CreateProcessA returns a Zero.

But if I check the err.LastDLLError in VB, it returns a 740 which means "process requires elevation".

If I use ShellExecute, it works fine - and UAC does not ask for elevation!

I can't tell why these few programs behave like this, because, as I mentioned, other programs that I feel are just as complex will run just fine with CreateProcessA.

BTW - These programs run perfectly under XP, Vista and Win 7 with UAC on or off.  And no elevation is required on any of them.

But - bottom line is ShellExecute seems to run ok, so I would recommend to the poster to try it instead of CreateProcess.

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your responding :)
I will try it to see if it run. I will tell you this.
Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

As promised I am posting response to Etienne in private email (thanks Etienne for providing repro information)

> I believe you are running in an 64-bit Windows 8 box and by default Visual Studio builds and runs the managed process as 64-bit process unless specified. Building and running your sample for x86 platform does not result in a silent crash, instead it throws a dialog box with an error.
>
> In the __CreateProcess definition, you are using uint as the parameter type. When running as a 64-bit process, the address field is 64-bit and it gets truncated when using uint. That causes an access violation and failure of the application. You should be using IntPtr which should work in both in both bitness.
>
> ```
> [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall, MethodCodeType = MethodCodeType.Runtime)]
> void __CreateProcess(
>      [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpApplicationName, 
>      [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpCommandLine, 
>      [In] ref _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, 
>      [In] ref _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, 
>      [In] int bInheritHandles, [In] uint dwCreationFlags, 
>      [In] IntPtr lpEnvironment, 
>      [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpCurrentDirectory, 
>      [In, ComAliasName("Debugger.Interop.CorDebug.ULONG_PTR")] uint lpStartupInfo, 
>      [In, ComAliasName("Debugger.Interop.CorDebug.ULONG_PTR")] uint lpProcessInformation, 
>      [In] CorDebugCreateProcessFlags debuggingFlags, 
>      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out ICorDebugProcess ppProcess);
> ```
>
> Also the API CreateDebuggingInterfaceFromVersion is obsolete and you’d want to use  ICLRRuntimeInfo::GetInterface for creating ICorDebug interfaces. You can refer to the CLR Managed Debugger Sample for code sample.
>
> Please let us know if this not solve your problem.

Conclusion: This is memory corruption that's unrelated to .NET4 or .NET4.5. The failure is random. Due to memory corruption, your app may have failed on .NET4 randomly, it just happens that you saw failure sooner in .NET4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your help. The problem is solved : there was a problem with the arguments of my CreateProcess function in ICorDebug, and its derivatives.
Just for test if I can have the same problem than user1748224, I have changed my manifest : if my project has not the administrator privileges I have the same message than you, user1748224. I don't know how it works in VB6, but in .Net, to avoid this problem, we just need to change the manifest of the main application.

Thank again :)